# react-intl currency displayed without decimals

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, react-intl

I have a requirement to display currency without decimals. We want the currency decorator ($), and the commas and spaces, as dictated by the locale, but no decimals.

I've tried the maximumFractionDigits set to 0. That works, but removes the commas and currency decorator.

Also, I have not been able to replicate the example in the docs at https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/API#number-formatting-apis:

```
formatNumber(1000, {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'}); // $1,000
```

I get $1,000.00.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out you need to specify both minimum and maximum fraction digits, like so:

```
formatNumber(1000, {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD',
  minimumFractionDigits: 0, maximumFractionDigits: 0}); // $1,000
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Certainly did help!